# jQuery FormBuilder validate only required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, formbuilder

I am using the jQuery FormBuilder plugin. Link: http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Now, when a user submits the form, I want to make sure all the required fields (with an *) are filled out, else the form  won't submit (I will get an error message 'An invalid form control with name='xxx' is not focusable.'). There are many types of  input in the form, including text, textarea, dropdown select, radio and checkbox etc. How do I validate all of them?

An example:

```
<form-template><fields><field type="text" required="true" label="Text Field" class="form-control" name="text-1531271871930" subtype="text"></field><field type="select" required="true" label="Select" class="form-control" name="select-1531271872850"><option label="Option 1" value="option-1" selected="true">Option 1</option><option label="Option 2" value="option-2">Option 2</option><option label="Option 3" value="option-3">Option 3</option></field><field type="radio-group" required="true" label="Radio Group" name="radio-group-1531271874156"><option label="Option 1" value="option-1">Option 1</option><option label="Option 2" value="option-2">Option 2</option><option label="Option 3" value="option-3">Option 3</option></field></fields></form-template>
```

Comment: Were you successful in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, i would totally just recommend using pure html and css. The required attribute works their. I'd say it's much easier

```
<form><input type="text" id="name" required><input type="submit"</form>
```

Then just use CSS to style it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I achieved this by utilizing the built in Required option for each field when building the form.  Just make sure your form is displayed within a FORM tag with a proper submit.